# Setting an id as a default foreign key in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am having challenges assigning a current user a role in a team the user is creating. I want to assign the user that creates the team the role of the captain which could be changed later.
 I'm currently using the create_asociation method that comes with has_one relationship, as this instantiates the values of the associated model, which i want to be instantiated with the current user but get the error `Can't mass assign protected attribute: captain`. Captain is a self join model with user as i will like to use `captain.teammates` and `team.captain`. 
 Below are the models involved.

User and Captain Model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_one :profile

 has_many :teammates, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "captain_id"
 belongs_to :captain, :class_name => "User"

 belongs_to :team

 # before_create :build_profile
 after_create :build_default_profile

 accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile
 attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :profile_attributes, :captain_id

 def build_default_profile
  Profile.create(user_id: self.id)
 end

 has_secure_password

 before_save { email.downcase! }
 before_save :create_remember_token

 VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
 validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, 
                uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
 validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }
 validates :password_confirmation, presence: true

 private

   def create_remember_token
    self.remember_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
   end
 end
```

Team Model

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :profiles, through: :users
 has_one :captain, :class_name => "User", foreign_key: :captain_id
 has_one :result, as: :result_table

 attr_accessible :teamname, :color, :result_attributes, :captain_attributes

 after_create :build_result_table
 after_create :build_default_captain
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :profiles
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :captain
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :result

 def build_result_table
  Result.create(result_table_id: self.id, result_table_type: self.class.name)
 end

 def build_default_captain
  # Team.captain = User 
  #  Captain.create(team_id: self.id, captain_id: user.id)
 end
end
```

User Controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
 before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy]
 before_filter :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]
 before_filter :admin_user,     only: :destroy

 def new
  @user = User.new
 end

 def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
  if @user.save!
   sign_in @user
   flash[:success] = "Welcome to the JHDC Mini Olympics Web Application; Thanks for singing Up"
   redirect_to user_profile_path(@user, @profile)
  else
   flash[:error_messages]
   render 'new'
  end
 end

 def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
 end

 def index
  @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page])
 end

 def edit
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
 end

 def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
   flash[:success] = "Profile Updated"
   redirect_to user_profile_path(@user, @profile)
  else
   render 'edit'
  end
 end

 def destroy
  User.find(params[:id]).destroy
  flash[:success] = "User deleted."
  redirect_to users_url
 end

 private

  def signed_in_user
   unless signed_in?
   store_location
   redirect_to signin_url, notice: "Please sign in."
  end

  def correct_user
   @user = User.find(params[:id])
   redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user?(@user)
  end

  def admin_user
   redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user.admin?
  end

  def user_params
   params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end
 end
end
```

Team Controller

```
class TeamsController < ApplicationController

 def new
  @team = Team.new
 end 

 def create
  @team = Team.new(params[:team])
  @captain = @team.create_captain(captain: current_user)
  if current_user.admin?
   if @team.save!
    flash[:success] = "Team created."
    redirect_to @team
   else
    flash[:error_messages]
    render 'new'
   end
  else
   flash[:error] = "Sorry, you don't have the authority to create a Team"
   redirect_to current_user
  end
 end

 def index
  @teams = Team.paginate(page: params[:page])
 end

 def show
  @team = Team.find(params[:id])
 end

 def edit
  if current_user.admin?
   @team = Team.find(params[:id])
  else
   flash[:error] = "Sorry you dont have the authourity to edit a Team"
   redirect_to current_user
  end
 end

 def update
  @team = Team.find(params[:id])
  if @team.update_attributes(params[:team])
   flash[:success] = "Team Updated"
   redirect_to @team
  else
   render 'edit'
  end
 end

 def destroy
  Team.find(params[:id]).destroy
  flash[:success] = "Team is deleted."
  redirect_to teams_url
 end


 private

   def team_params
    params.require(:team).permit(:teamname, :color)
   end
 end
```

The admin is currently a way i'm using to restrict the user that can create a team but i plan to use gems like `declarative authorization` to create role based authorization. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are getting is because the attribute :captain is not declared as attr_accessible

Either set the attribute :captain in your list of attr_accessible for the User model, or change the code form

```
Captain.create(team_id: self.id, captain_id: user.id)
```

to

```
captain = Captain.new
captain.team_id = self.id
captain.captain_id = user.id
captain.create
```

in this way, the attribute won't be set by mass-assignment and won't raise the error

---

Edited

After checking your code twice, just realized that you don't have a Captain model, actually :captain is a relation for the user and a relation from the Team to the User.

So on Team model, take off the build_default_captain stuff and the after_create :build_default_captain, I would say to replace with something like

```
after_save :set_default_captain

def set_default_captain
  if captain_id_changed?
    profiles.each do |user|
      user.captain = captain
      user.save
    end
  end
end
```

so every time the captain_id change for the model, you change the captain_id of all its profiles (users)

Then on the Team controller, on the action create, instead of

```
@team = Team.new(params[:team])
@captain = @team.create_captain(captain: current_user)
```

do something like

```
@team = Team.new(params[:team])
@team.captain = current_user
if current_user.admin?
  if @team.save!
    current_user.update_attribute(:team_id, @team.id)
    flash[:success] = "Team created."
    redirect_to @team
  else
    flash[:error_messages]
    render 'new'
  end
else
  flash[:error] = "Sorry, you don't have the authority to create a Team"
  redirect_to current_user
end
```

so on the last part of the code, you set the captain of the team to the current user and set the user team to the current team once its saved, you can also improve the code with current_user.build_team to avoid saving current_user.update_attribute

Comment: I understand your logic, @rorra but I now get the error ` uninitialized constant Team::Captain` .

Comment: The line ` captain_id_changed? ` is throwing an error, its been seen as a method which isn't defined. Please explain that part.

Comment: got it, added new answer after I saw your comment

Comment: On your Team Model, you have an attribute which is named captain_id which I'm seeing on the code has_one :captain, :class_name => "User", foreign_key: :captain_id, so with that you are saying "every time the captain_id field is changed, execute the next code", the idea is that every time you change the captain for the team, it will change the captain for all the profiles on the team, pretty weird that captain_id_changed? didn't work, the doc is on http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html, you can try with captain_changed? but i guess it will also throw the error